# Simple valid Regex do not match

Tags: javascript, regex

Whats wrong with this ?

```
var attrRegex = /^.*[[].*[]]$/;
var attrKeys = key.match(attrRegex);
```

This should match `some-var[data-key]`

Comment: Please provide the exact key value that you use and also be specific on your question. There is no proper information that could help someone to provide an answer

Comment: I put your regex and your string into http://www.regexpal.com/ and it matches. Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @Patashu attrKey is always null.

Comment: @Abc The regex matches `some-var[data-key]`, so the problem is not your regex, it's your data or your program :) (or that your regex does what you say it's meant to, but not what it actually needs to)

Comment: @Patashu: The regex tester uses XRegExp, which is an external library and may parse the regex differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify `[` and `]`, you should escape them `\[` and `\]`.

```
/^.*\[.*\]$/
```

**However, your current regex will only check that there is a `[` followed by a `]`, and the `]` is at the end of the string.** It doesn't validate that there are exactly 1 opening bracket `[` and 1 close bracket `]`, or whether the brackets `[]` are balanced.

If you want to make sure that there is only 1 pair of brackets, and disallow the newline characters that are disallowed by `.`:

```
/^[^\[\]\n\r\u2028\u2029]*\[[^\[\]\n\r\u2028\u2029]*\]$/
```

Break down:

```
^
[^\[\]\n\r\u2028\u2029]*   # Exclude [, ], and newline characters
                           # \n\r\u2028\u2029 are originally excluded by .
\[                         # Literal [
[^\[\]\n\r\u2028\u2029]*
\]                         # Literal ]
$
```

---

#### How is your original regex `/^.*[[].*[]]$/` interpreted?

On Firefox, from my testing, the regex is interpreted as such:

```
^    # Nothing interesting
.*   # ...
[[]  # Character class containing [
.*   # ...
[]   # Empty character class!!! NOTHING can be matched
]    # Literal ]
$    # ...
```

Not sure about other browsers, but when you write regex, please do escaping properly to avoid unexpected behaviour.

Depending on the language, `]` or both `[]` has special meaning within a character class `[]` and must be escaped.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that arbitrary levels of bracket-matching are beyond a normal regex (although possible with Perl regexes).

Comment: @michaelb958: As long as there's only one pair of brackets (as outlined in this answer), regex is just fine. It gets complicated if there could be nested brackets, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @michaelb958: Yes. I just give some example of possibly unwanted input that may pass validation with the first regex.